# key.char gives AttributeError when using Key.f5 in Python Pynput

Tags: python, attributeerror, keycode, pynput

Im trying to make a very simple program that presses the <kbd>F5</kbd> key when I press another key (example <kbd>q</kbd>).
Whenever I use regular characters a-z I compare using

```
if key.char == 'q':
```

This works fine until I introduce `Key.f5` (or any other `Key.`)

```
if key.char == 'q':
    keyboard.press(Key.f5)
    keyboard.release(Key.f5)
```

I then get this error:

```
if f(*args) is False:
File "C:\Users\lkl\Desktop\combination-1.py", line 17, in on_release
if key.char == 'q':
AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'char'
```

I have tried renaming `key` to `key1` and other names. I have tried to create a controller called `keyboard1` and other names. I have tried to isolate the following code in its own function:

```
keyboard.press(Key.f5)
keyboard.release(Key.f5)
```

I have tried to catch the error with Try Except statements. The Error still comes. And it ends the execution.

I have tried avoid to `key.char` by simply comparing key with the Unicode and html code for the character. This triggers no action when pressing <kbd>q</kbd>

```
if key == 'U+0071':
```

The thing is, the program executes the `F5`command even when I use `key.char` but the AttributeError stops the program.

I am able to make this run:

```
if key == Key.shift_l:
    keyboard.press(Key.f5)
    keyboard.release(Key.f5)
```

but I need the key to be a simple a-z key, because the machine is receiving the key through a keylogger on a seperate machine. And it can only send/receive non-special keys. eg. numbers and letters.

This is completely wrinkling my brain. I can't find a single way to send `F5` while listening for `'q'`.

Here is the full code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener as ms
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as kb
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import os
import sys
import subprocess

keyboard = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key.char == 'q':
        keyboard.press(Key.f5)
        keyboard.release(Key.f5)
    if key == "a":
        subprocess.call("C:/Users/lkl/Desktop/fastsafelargetest - Copy.vbs", shell=True)
    if key == 'z':
        subprocess.call("C:/Users/lkl/Desktop/autofill.vbs", shell=True)
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        pass
    else:
        #subprocess.call("C:/Users/lkl/Desktop/fastsafelargetest - Copy.vbs", shell=True)
        print('Released')

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

# Collect events until released
with ms(
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    with kb(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @jim-todd answer i found the python module "keyboard".
Its not a very elegant solution but it technically provides a workaround for the problem. I use this line to check for key input:

```
keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
```

rename my pynput controller to keyboard1

```
keyboard1 = Controller()
```

And the entire code for this problem can look like this (not all imports here are necessary).

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener as ms
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as kb
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import keyboard
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

keyboard1 = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        keyboard1.press(Key.f5)
        keyboard1.release(Key.f5)
        print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))
        time.sleep(0.05)
        break
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with ms() as listener:
    with kb(
            on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to test whether the key object has a char before using it.

One way to do that which I used in my application with pynput would be to do something like this (adapted from your code)

```
def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if hasattr(key, 'char'):
        if key.char == 'q':
            keyboard.press(Key.f5)
            keyboard.release(Key.f5)
        if key == "a":
            subprocess.call("C:/Users/lkl/Desktop/fastsafelargetest - Copy.vbs", shell=True)
        if key == 'z':
            subprocess.call("C:/Users/lkl/Desktop/autofill.vbs", shell=True)
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
```

Note how all keys that use char codes are inside of this part

> if hasattr(key, 'char'):

That will avoid the error :)

btw, on [pynput's documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) they do it a different way, by doing a try-catch on the AttributeError, but I try to avoid those especially for performance-critical things like checking the keyboard every frame in a game.

Comment: I understand its an old post but I came across it while searching for the same issue and figured i'd put an actually working solution with the right library here because the existing answers weren't really solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can used keyboard.pressed function for the if condition like this:

```
if keyboard.pressed('q'):
```

This would be working.

Comment: Just tried it. For some reason it fires off for any key press. Not just 'q'. It starts a recursion where the F5 press triggers the next F5 press and so on. Tried both making if statement and a while loop.
`def on_press(key):  
while keyboard.pressed('q'):  
        keyboard.press(Key.f5)  
        keyboard.release(Key.f5)  
        print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))  
        time.sleep(0.05)  
        break  
    if key == Key.esc:  
        return False  

with ms() as listener:  
    with kb(
            on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()  `